# How to web scrape and access <script> wtih bs4 using python

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, scrape

Im trying to scrape the data from "https://www.deadstock.ca/products/adidas-futurepacer-grey-one"

I want to be able to read the variant data which looks like this:

```
<script>
window.ShopifyAnalytics = window.ShopifyAnalytics || {};
window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta = window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta || {};
  window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta.currency = 'CAD';
  var meta = {"product":{"id":223724142613,"vendor":"Adidas","type":"Footwear 
- QS","variants":[{"id":3063231774741,"price":26000,"name":"adidas 
Futurepacer \/ Grey One - 8","public_title":"8","sku":"AQ0907-Grey One-8"}, 
{"id":3063231807509,"price":26000,"name":"adidas Futurepacer \/ Grey One - 
8.5","public_title":"8.5","sku":"AQ0907-Grey One-8.5"}, 
{"id":3063231840277,"price":26000,"name":"adidas Futurepacer \/ Grey One - 
9","public_title":"9","sku":"AQ0907-Grey One-9"}, 
{"id":3063231873045,"price":26000,"name":"adidas Futurepacer \/ Grey One - 
9.5","public_title":"9.5","sku":"AQ0907-Grey One-9.5"}, 
{"id":3063231905813,"price":26000,"name":"adidas Futurepacer \/ Grey One - 
10","public_title":"10","sku":"AQ0907-Grey One-10"}, 
{"id":3063231938581,"price":26000,"name":"adidas Futurepacer \/ Grey One - 
10.5","public_title":"10.5","sku":"AQ0907-Grey One-10.5"}, 
{"id":3063231971349,"price":26000,"name":"adidas Futurepacer \/ Grey One - 
11","public_title":"11","sku":"AQ0907-Grey One-11"}, 
{"id":3063232004117,"price":26000,"name":"adidas Futurepacer \/ Grey One - 
12","public_title":"12","sku":"AQ0907-Grey One-12"}, 
{"id":3063232036885,"price":26000,"name":"adidas Futurepacer \/ Grey One - 
 13","public_title":"13","sku":"AQ0907-Grey One-13"}]},"page": 
{"pageType":"product","resourceType":"product","resourceId":223724142613}};
  for (var attr in meta) {
    window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta[attr] = meta[attr];
  }
</script>
```

I don't think im targeting the  properly. I want the code to be able to print all the "id": numbers. Here is my code so far, im still new to bs4 but any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import lxml

link = urllib.request.urlopen ('https://www.deadstock.ca/products/adidas-futurepacer-grey-one').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(link,'lxml')

for variants in soup.find_all('script'):
    print (variants)
```

I tried something like this ontop of @Andrej Kesely answer.

```
for id in data['variants']:
size = id['variants']['option1']
variantid = id['variants']['id']

print (size)
print (variantid)
```

Its coming back with a keyerror though, i just want it to show all the ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this web site you need to target  with `id="ProductJson-product-template"`. It contains JSON with all variants:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import json

link = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.deadstock.ca/products/adidas-futurepacer-grey-one').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(link,'lxml')

variant = soup.find('script', id='ProductJson-product-template')
data = json.loads(variant.text)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "available": true,
    "compare_at_price": null,
    "compare_at_price_max": 0,
    "compare_at_price_min": 0,
    "compare_at_price_varies": false,
    "content": "<p>adidas digs into its vault to redesign the 1984 Micropacer, a computerized shoe that was designed to track running statistics. Today, the adidas Futurepacer takes cues from the Micropacer, and the more recent NMD collection, to deliver a futuristic lifestyle runner. Featuring a premium leather upper, complete with a modernized lace cover, the adidas Futurepacer sits on a Boost midsole for lightweight cushioning and responsiveness. NMD inspired bumpers are found at the heel and forefoot for added style and stability.</p>\n<ul>\n<li>Premium leather upper</li>\n<li>Premium leather lace cover</li>\n<li>Subtle adidas branding</li>\n<li>Boost midsole</li>\n<li>adidas midsole plugs</li>\n<li>Grey One</li>\n</ul>\n<p>Product Code: AQ0907</p>",
    "created_at": "2018-03-05T14:23:57-08:00",
    "description": "<p>adidas digs into its vault to redesign the 1984 Micropacer, a computerized shoe that was designed to track running statistics. Today, the adidas Futurepacer takes cues from the Micropacer, and the more recent NMD collection, to deliver a futuristic lifestyle runner. Featuring a premium leather upper, complete with a modernized lace cover, the adidas Futurepacer sits on a Boost midsole for lightweight cushioning and responsiveness. NMD inspired bumpers are found at the heel and forefoot for added style and stability.</p>\n<ul>\n<li>Premium leather upper</li>\n<li>Premium leather lace cover</li>\n<li>Subtle adidas branding</li>\n<li>Boost midsole</li>\n<li>adidas midsole plugs</li>\n<li>Grey One</li>\n</ul>\n<p>Product Code: AQ0907</p>",
    "featured_image": "//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0616/3517/products/aq0907_adidas_futurepacer_grey_one.jpg?v=1530313621",
    "handle": "adidas-futurepacer-grey-one",
    "id": 223724142613,
    "images": [
        "//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0616/3517/products/aq0907_adidas_futurepacer_grey_one.jpg?v=1530313621",
        "//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0616/3517/products/aq0907_adidas_futurepacer_grey_one_1.jpg?v=1531247436",
        "//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0616/3517/products/aq0907_adidas_futurepacer_grey_one_2.jpg?v=1531247441",
        "//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0616/3517/products/aq0907_adidas_futurepacer_grey_one_3.jpg?v=1531247444",
        "//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0616/3517/products/aq0907_adidas_futurepacer_grey_one_4.jpg?v=1531247447",
        "//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0616/3517/products/aq0907_adidas_futurepacer_grey_one_5.jpg?v=1531247449"
    ],
    "options": [
        "US Size"
    ],
    "price": 26000,
    "price_max": 26000,
    "price_min": 26000,
    "price_varies": false,
    "published_at": "2018-07-14T12:00:00-07:00",
    "tags": [
        "07142018",
        "cf-type-footwear-qs",
        "cf-us-size-10",
        "cf-us-size-10-5",
        "cf-us-size-11",
        "cf-us-size-12",
        "cf-us-size-13",
        "cf-us-size-8",
        "cf-us-size-8-5",
        "cf-us-size-9",
        "cf-us-size-9-5",
        "cf-vendor-adidas",
        "free_shipping",
        "limit-quantity",
        "plsmerch"
    ],
    "title": "adidas Futurepacer / Grey One",
    "type": "Footwear - QS",
    "variants": [
        {
            "available": true,
            "barcode": "193050061142",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "featured_image": null,
            "id": 3063231774741,
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "inventory_quantity": 3,
            "name": "adidas Futurepacer / Grey One - 8",
            "option1": "8",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "options": [
                "8"
            ],
            "price": 26000,
            "public_title": "8",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "sku": "AQ0907-Grey One-8",
            "taxable": true,
            "title": "8",
            "weight": 0
        },
        {
            "available": true,
            "barcode": "193050061159",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "featured_image": null,
            "id": 3063231807509,
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "inventory_quantity": 2,
            "name": "adidas Futurepacer / Grey One - 8.5",
            "option1": "8.5",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "options": [
                "8.5"
            ],
            "price": 26000,
            "public_title": "8.5",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "sku": "AQ0907-Grey One-8.5",
            "taxable": true,
            "title": "8.5",
            "weight": 0
        },
        {
            "available": true,
            "barcode": "193050061166",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "featured_image": null,
            "id": 3063231840277,
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "inventory_quantity": 6,
            "name": "adidas Futurepacer / Grey One - 9",
            "option1": "9",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "options": [
                "9"
            ],
            "price": 26000,
            "public_title": "9",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "sku": "AQ0907-Grey One-9",
            "taxable": true,
            "title": "9",
            "weight": 0
        },
        {
            "available": true,
            "barcode": "193050061173",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "featured_image": null,
            "id": 3063231873045,
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "inventory_quantity": 5,
            "name": "adidas Futurepacer / Grey One - 9.5",
            "option1": "9.5",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "options": [
                "9.5"
            ],
            "price": 26000,
            "public_title": "9.5",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "sku": "AQ0907-Grey One-9.5",
            "taxable": true,
            "title": "9.5",
            "weight": 0
        },
        {
            "available": true,
            "barcode": "193050061180",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "featured_image": null,
            "id": 3063231905813,
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "inventory_quantity": 6,
            "name": "adidas Futurepacer / Grey One - 10",
            "option1": "10",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "options": [
                "10"
            ],
            "price": 26000,
            "public_title": "10",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "sku": "AQ0907-Grey One-10",
            "taxable": true,
            "title": "10",
            "weight": 0
        },
        {
            "available": true,
            "barcode": "193050061197",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "featured_image": null,
            "id": 3063231938581,
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "inventory_quantity": 6,
            "name": "adidas Futurepacer / Grey One - 10.5",
            "option1": "10.5",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "options": [
                "10.5"
            ],
            "price": 26000,
            "public_title": "10.5",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "sku": "AQ0907-Grey One-10.5",
            "taxable": true,
            "title": "10.5",
            "weight": 0
        },
        {
            "available": true,
            "barcode": "193050061203",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "featured_image": null,
            "id": 3063231971349,
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "inventory_quantity": 1,
            "name": "adidas Futurepacer / Grey One - 11",
            "option1": "11",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "options": [
                "11"
            ],
            "price": 26000,
            "public_title": "11",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "sku": "AQ0907-Grey One-11",
            "taxable": true,
            "title": "11",
            "weight": 0
        },
        {
            "available": true,
            "barcode": "193050061210",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "featured_image": null,
            "id": 3063232004117,
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "inventory_quantity": 4,
            "name": "adidas Futurepacer / Grey One - 12",
            "option1": "12",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "options": [
                "12"
            ],
            "price": 26000,
            "public_title": "12",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "sku": "AQ0907-Grey One-12",
            "taxable": true,
            "title": "12",
            "weight": 0
        },
        {
            "available": true,
            "barcode": "193050061227",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "featured_image": null,
            "id": 3063232036885,
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "inventory_quantity": 1,
            "name": "adidas Futurepacer / Grey One - 13",
            "option1": "13",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "options": [
                "13"
            ],
            "price": 26000,
            "public_title": "13",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "sku": "AQ0907-Grey One-13",
            "taxable": true,
            "title": "13",
            "weight": 0
        }
    ],
    "vendor": "Adidas"
}
```

Comment: Awesome, now from that code how do i go about just targeting the ID in each of the variants?

Comment: @TNC data is just a classic Python dictionary, so you will work with it like another dictionary.

Comment: I tried something like this just now, not sure if im on the right path though. edited post.